# Joining a table and selecting where NOT exists

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:
[image]

> **employees:** A table with all my employees
>   **teams:** A table with teams created
>   **team_employees:** A table with a relation of a team with a list of employees.

So, basically what I need is to select all the employees that don't have a team, within a team. For example, if you see, in the table team_employees, the id_team #2 doesn't have the id_employee #2. The query select I'm looking for should give me the ID employee #2 (but only of the Team ID #2)

I've already tried doing a `LEFT JOIN` like this but no luck, as I thought it would give me a NULL in the team_id field, but nope:

```
SELECT te.id_team AS id_team, e.id, e.name
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN team_employees te
ON te.id_employee = e.id
WHERE id_team = 2
GROUP BY e.id
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Use this form of left join

```
SELECT te.id_team AS id_team, e.id, e.name
FROM employees e
LEFT JOIN team_employees te ON te.id_employee = e.id AND te.id_team = 2
WHERE te.id_team IS NULL
```

Sometimes called "left excluding join". What you need to do is place the `e.id_team = 2` into the join conditions, not the where clause. Then the where clause is used to locate all rows with no match to the team table.

Alternative:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     select null 
     from team_employees te
     where te.id_employee = e.id AND te.id_team = 2
     )
```